# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

> java.lang.NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.marsad.earningapp.activity.RegisterActivity$4.onComplete(RegisterActivity.java:138)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6711)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

Error

> reference.child(currentUser.getUid()).setValue(userInformation).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {...

Here is the RegisterActivity.java

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText nameEdit, emailEdit, phoneEdit, passwordEdit;
    private Button loginBtn, signupBtn;

    private static final String TAG = "SignUpActivity";
    String defaultImage = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/earning-app-27780.appspot.com/o/woman.png?alt=media&token=4d66f140-4bd9-4a25-9838-cca28ebf48bb";

    private FirebaseDatabase userinfoDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        nameEdit = findViewById(R.id.nameEditSignup);
        emailEdit = findViewById(R.id.emailEditSignup);
        phoneEdit = findViewById(R.id.phoneEditSignup);
        passwordEdit = findViewById(R.id.passwordEditSignup);
        loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginBtnSignup);
        signupBtn = findViewById(R.id.registerBTn);

        userinfoDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = userinfoDatabase.getReference("Users");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        signupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = nameEdit.getText().toString();
                String phone = phoneEdit.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)){

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
                        nameEdit.setError("Enter Your Name");
                        nameEdit.requestFocus();
                    }

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)){
                        phoneEdit.setError("Enter Your Phone Number");
                        phoneEdit.requestFocus();
                    }

                } else {

                    showRegisterDialog();
                    authenticationListener();

                }
            }
        });


    }

    private void authenticationListener(){

        final String email = emailEdit.getText().toString();
        final String password = passwordEdit.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                emailEdit.setError("Enter Your Email");
                emailEdit.requestFocus();
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                passwordEdit.setError("Enter Your Password");
                passwordEdit.requestFocus();
            }

        } else
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    RegisterModel userInformation = new RegisterModel();

                    userInformation.setEmail(email);
                    userInformation.setName(nameEdit.getText().toString());
                    userInformation.setPassword(password);
                    userInformation.setPhone(phoneEdit.getText().toString());
                    userInformation.setRupees(0);
                    userInformation.setPoints(0);
                    userInformation.setImage(defaultImage);

                    reference.child(currentUser.getUid()).setValue(userInformation).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            //user registered successfully
                            sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            //user failed to register
                            sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                            showRegisterErrorDialog();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //Error
                    sweetAlertDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                    showRegisterErrorDialog();
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines of code

```
String currentUserId;
```

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();


if(currentUser!= null) {
    currentUserId = currentUser.getUid(); //Do what you need to do with the id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`currentUser` is null, which means no user is signed in.  You need to check for this case before calling `getUid()` on it.

Comment: Please add some details